# Dual monitor wont play media centre on primary screen

Tags: display, monitor, xbmc

I am running ubuntu 13.04 on a laptop that is connected to my TV. Everything seems to work fine but when I open my media centre (XBMC) it will only run in full screen on the laptop. I have changed the display settings to a dual screen set up with the TV as the launcher screen but the only way i can get XBMC on the TV is to run it in a window and drag it over to the TV. Can anyone help me? Should I have version 12.04 instead?

Answer (score 1):

No help? ok... here's the answer: Go back to Windows....